# Select worksheet from file.dialog then get a few data from it in the active cell

Tags: vba, excel

When my VBA script cannot figure out how to "call" the selected worksheet

What i need to do:

- Select a file (if it can automatically pull from all files in folder would be great, but no idea how...)
- Copy some data from it and paste in the current opened excel

  ```
  Private Sub openDialog()
  Dim fd As Office.FileDialog

  Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

   With fd

    .AllowMultiSelect = True

    ' Set the title of the dialog box.
    .Title = "Please select the file."

    ' Clear out the current filters, and add our own.
    .Filters.Clear
    .Filters.Add "All Files", "*.*"

    ' Show the dialog box. If the .Show method returns True, the
    ' user picked at least one file. If the .Show method returns
    ' False, the user clicked Cancel.
    If .Show = True Then


  'edit data
  Range("K4").Select
  ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=LEFT(RIGHT(R[-2]C[-10],65),20)"
  Range("L4").Select
  Application.CutCopyMode = False
  ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[5]C[-3]"
  Range("M4").Select
  Application.CutCopyMode = False
  ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[6]C[-4]"
  Range("N4").Select
  Application.CutCopyMode = False
  ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[7]C[-5]"
  Range("O4").Select
  Application.CutCopyMode = False
  ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[8]C[-6]"

  ' copy data
  Range("K4:O4").Select
  Selection.Copy

  ' paste on active cell
  For i = 1 To LastRow
  ws.Range ("A" & i)
  ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
  Next i

  'DO NOT KNOW WHAT TO USE HERE

    End If
   End With

  End Sub
  ```

Comment: Why are you creaking a loop to paste the data? Do you just need to find the last row on column A and then paste the data there?

Comment: I have many and many data in pdf, so i am converting PDF to excel, and then copying one by one, i will use this macro to copy 4 cells and place one by one in another excel so then i can plot and work with those values. For example, my data is A2, K9, K10, K11, K12, i want them to be in A1,B1,C1,D1,E1 (in another excel) respectively, next file will be recorded in A2,B2....

Comment: It sounds like you will need a loop, but not in the way you are using it. If you are opening multiple files, this needs to be where your loop starts (for each file calculate “these” cells, copy “these cells” then find last row (+1) on your excel and paste data there. Restart loop for next file.